# how to design tables which share some attributes but have also not common attributes in a database

Tags: database

I'm building a database for a real estate agency. And I'm working on an ER model and i've encountered a problem.

I devided the tables into appartments, houses, land, projects
Now in the tables i have attributes that are shared on all 4 tables (location, price, size ...) but also i have some special atributes on every table.

Now i think this isn't the best solution i could work with and will get alot of extra work later when implementing controlers with the database.

I've thought about joining multiple tables with a foreign key but then I don't see the reasons i would do that.

What would be the most practical solution to my problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classical problem of object-relational mapping and there some different solutions to this problem, each with ist own pros and cons, depending on your use case.

1.) Use completely separate tables, but map them in your code to objects which share the same superclass (or interface).

2.) Use the same table with a superset of columns. Some of the columns are then only used e.g. for one of the subclasses, some for all. You will have one extra column (called a tag-column) to differentiate e.g. between appartments and houses.

3.) Use a base table with the common columns and (joinable) extension tables for columns specific to one of the subclasses. (Think this is what you already proposed.)

Solution 1 requires either an ORM Framework (e.g. like Hibernate for Java) or your own hand written mapping code, if you start on SQL level. Maybe this is what you meant with "extra work". However, solution 1 does not allow to get/update/delete appartments as well as houses with 1 SQL operation. This may or may not be an issue in your Project (probably not).

Solution 2 is very appropriate, if the number of shared columns is bigger than the number of columns only used one of the subclasses (e.g. > 60%), else it may induce some overhead in the DB with many fields beeing null most of the time. Also, it is e.g. not possible to have some DB NOT NULL constraints on fields only used by one of the subclasses.

Solution 3 maybe a good solution, if the non-shared columns are much bigger than shared columns. However, it leads to more complex code if you are not using a ORM Framework which supports this. It may also have some performance impacts e.g. you cannot define an index with one column in the main table and another column in one of the joined tables.

Anyway: Unless your project is very simple I recommend strongly to use an ORM Framework (e.g. Hibernate if you are using Java) if this is possible. The effort to learn it will pay off very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish what you want to do, is use hierarchy.

The idea is create a parent table, such as `property`, with the common attributes. Then, each child table, will have their special attributes, and a foreign key to link them with the parent table.

```
Property {
  - id,
  - prop1,
  - prop2,
  ...
}

Appartment {
  - id,
  - property_id,
  - specialProp1,
  - specialProp2,
  ...
}
```

I hope it works for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

You dont realy have a problem but a choise to make ^^. Eather way would work, it all depends on the amount of data you will store.

A solution would be to make your 4 tables without propeties at all, and then have a dedicated table for all the properties, and leave null the ones not used for a specific table.

Just store the properti_id in the 4 tables, no need to define a actual constraint.