# Best practice so a database supports to query different entries with some common attributes

Tags: mysql, django

### This is an abstract description of my problem without any specific technology/framwork.

I would like to know what the best practice is to model the following (toy)
example: Suppose I am selling toys. I have f.e. teddy bears and small elephants
and zebras. They share the following attributes:

- price
- number of eyes
- fluffyness-rating
- name
- description

So I would like to create a table "toy" that stores this information and makes
it easy, f.e. to query the 10 cheapest toys.

I also want to store the animals explicitly, with all the information I get
from the manufacturer, let's say their weight, or how many colors they have.

This includes information that is only given for a subset of animals, f.e.  the
elephants have a "number of tusks", while the zebras do not. There are two
reasons for that:

- I might be using some of the common information (f.e.: weight) in the toys
  table at a later point.
- maybe I am going to run a different service that only lists animals with tusks.

My problem is: I would like to use reference fields, so a toy only has
references to some of the fields in **one** table, f.e. the zebra table.
If it is a zebra, it can not refer to the elephant table.

But every toy has to have the common attributes I mentioned above (price,
number of eyes, …).

### And specificly, I planned to use django and it's ORM.

I know that I could join over all the different tables and let them implement
some of the common names, but a) I want to be able to add other types of
elements (f.e. via plugins) and b) I would like to assure that every model
implements the common names!

Also I could use a nosql database, that would be very flexible, but I am
interested in solving this problem with something traditional (to learn
something).

(Final remark: I am more interested in how you would solve such a problem. And which nice properties your solution has. I am sure I described a very fundamental problem that is part of the bigger question: How should I design my application, which could be best answered by working thoroughly through some book …)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021772/how-to-design-tables-which-share-some-attributes-but-have-also-not-common-attrib

Comment: I am not going to delete the question, because I had such fun writing all this and there might be others that find this interesting or have an interesting opinion …

Answer (score 0):

I am going to model an abstract base class (that has f.e. a 'name') and then the class that creates f.e. the zebras is in charge of mapping from the custom 'zebra_name' to the 'name' of the abstract base class. That solves all my problems, I guess :).

Source: [Django models.Model superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625010/django-models-model-superclass)

**Edit:** this solves the problem how I can design the DB, but not how I can query it, since ABC can not be queried.

Answer (score -1):

In general it is not possible to query abstract base classes:
[How to query abstract-class-based objects in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797982/how-to-query-abstract-class-based-objects-in-django) specificly https://stackoverflow.com/a/9981317/3750254 seems to answer the problem: Just use inheritance and select the subclasses that match. However, wouldn't that give me **all** the subclasses (with all the attributes I might not need)?